# mamp apache won't start: Permission denied: make_sock

Tags: apache, mamp

I've had mamp running for about a year and suddenly today it stopped server files from one moment to the next.

There were no errors in the apache error log file in the logs directory, and restarting my mac and mamp have resulted in mysql starting but not apache.

I've tried using apachectl start and finally got the error:

```
apachectl -k restart
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using     MacBook-Pro.local for ServerName
httpd not running, trying to start
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Nothings changed on my mac, any ideas?

Comment: Have you changed anything with your system? Hostname, installed software etc?

Comment: nope no changes whatsoever. finally gave up and reinstalled works fine again now